# java - How to upgrade project from gwt 2.5.0 to gwt 2.8.2

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, eclipse-plugin, java-6

I am trying to upgrade my `GWT` application, which is using `GWT 2.5.0` and `JDK 6`, so I am wondering if any one can help me figuring out the impact or the thinks that should be upgraded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um...  Upgrade your jars to 2.8.2, and (ideally) set your java language level to 1.8 (and enjoy using lambdas).

If there are compilation errors, fix them, but there probably won't be, as the gwt project generally avoids making backwards incompatible changes.

Instead of listing everything that *could* go wrong but *probably won't* it would be better to just update to 2.8.2, and if any errors appear, hop over to the gwtproject gitter and ask about any specific problem you are having.

https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt

Comment: Full disclosure: I am a cofounder of a gwt services company, vertispan.com.  We will gladly spend a few minutes for free helping you in chat or stack overflow, but if you run into any serious problems, we offer professional help from leading experts in the GWT community.

Comment: Also, jdk 6 is no longer supported, and 7 is already End Of Life.

You should really be upgrading to java 8 (Java 9 support in GWT 2.8.2 is not great; it will only work if using classpath instead of modulepath, but if you are on JDK 6, you will definitely be using classpath).

Comment: It was on JDK 6, but now i changed it to JDK 7

Comment: The End of Life for Java 7 was in 2015.  I strongly urge you to upgrade to java 8, if you want to get critical security and performance improvements. https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/Oracle-Ends-Java-7Public-Updates